# Symmetric Distribution for MCMC Continuous Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a sampling distribution $g(X^{'}| X=x)$ such that

$$ \log(X^{'})|X=x\sim N(\log(x), \sigma^2)$$

This ensures that our samples are in $(0, \infty)$. Now I would like to use the Metropolis algorithm but am not sure if this sampling distribution is symmetric.

It seems if I think about the sampling distribution in terms of points that $g(x_1| X=x_2) = g(x_2| X=x_1)$ as $\log()$ is a bijection. However if I think about it in terms of neighborhoods around points it no longer makes sense.

What is a proof for whether this is a symmetric distribution or not?